# Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS live - 2 Displays

Tags: display-manager

I booted an Ubuntu live OS and wonder why my second Monitor shows up in the settings. I installed windows 10 on my harddrive which shows 2 Displays, too.
The second one, an Acer V223W isn't even plugged so  I wonder how Ubuntu can detect it.

Can anybody help me to solve this?